# Display Forms filled out PDF on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, pdf

I Used webServices to get Pdf URL and displaying it using UIWebView. Some of those files are PDF forms that have been filled out. They display correctly on my PC and my android phone.  However, they show up as blank forms on my iPad2.  Why?  I have tried `GoodReader`, `Dropbox`, `PDFReader` -- they show the PDF form, but none of the information that has been added to the form are mapped.  It seems like this is an iPad limitation.  Any help or solutions would be great.

[image]

[image]

here i have shown two images. First one is original screen shots and second one is my iPad Screen shots. In this second screen shots fill out data is displaying (which are displaying blue color in first image)...

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobilews.filehvut.com/Docs/000464/Form2290V_1894.pdf"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Update your question with your code.

Comment: so you will get the URL from the API response. with that you need to load the web view. Am i right?

Comment: Its seems to be a problem with the URL source. Font not supported. Need to fix in web page CSS>

Comment: We have changed font also.. but there is no use .

Comment: i have faced the same issue. Issue get resolved only after the creative persons changed some thing in .css file related to font.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55439/discussion-between-ssn-and-ganapathy).

Comment: Hi, did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you getting following type of string : 
http://mobilews.filehvut.com/Docs/000464/Form2290V_1894.pdf

Here is the working code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mobilews.filehvut.com/Docs/000464/Form2290V_1894.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[web loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Hope it'll work for you.